# Add int to hex ("/x??" form) with python

Tags: python

```
hex = "\xc0\x1d\x00\x00"
n = 4

result = chr(int(hex, 16) + n)
```

I'm reading an .avi file and extracting "hex" from it
I need to be able to operate on it before putting it back in the file
but I'm struggling with the conversions, is there any way I could do this ?

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xc0\x1d\x00\x00'

edit : more details

I heard .avi files have frame indexes that start at "idx1", the 4 bytes following ("\xc0\x1d\x00\x00") describe the length of that said index.
Since I'm duplicating frames I need to fix the size of the index to make the file readable again.

Comment: Look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: You need to do only one hex value. You are trying to calculate 4 different hex values at once, Python cannot do that in one function call.

Comment: Can you indicate the desired output and provide more examples?

Comment: edited the original post ! not sure if I should of answered here or if that's just fine since it's my first time here, thanks though

Comment: `struct.unpack('<i',"\xc0\x1d\x00\x00")[0]` ⇒ `7616`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your using python 2.7 ?

```
arr = []
for h in hex:
    arr.append(ord(h))
print( arr ) 

>>> [192, 29, 0, 0]
```

Then you could compress to a 32 int or just add 4 to the LSB ?

```
def addToBytearray(arr, n):
    l = len(arr) - 1 
    for i,x in enumerate(arr[::-1]):
        x += n
        n = x >> 8
        arr[l-i] =  x & 0xff
        if n == 0 : 
            break
    if n != 0 : 
        print( "overflow error" ) 
    return arr


print(addToBytearray(arr,4))
>>> [192, 29, 0, 4]

print(addToBytearray(arr,304))
>>> [192, 29, 1, 52]
```

if you want to only use built-ins ( should be easier with 3.x )